# How to rewrite blank folder request with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a big problem with my website as only index.php is under public_html folder and all other files in include folder when I type http://example.com/include/ it gives full directory listing with all files displayed please help me to redirect user when he makes folder request.

Answer (score 0):

You can chmod the folder so that it can't be viewed by other visitors.

Chmod to: 750.

Comment: but i need to access the folder via script would it be possible

Comment: please tell me in detail how to chmod

Comment: You'll need to use FTP or some kind of file-manager system to chmod the folder on your server. Usually there is an option available when right-clicking the folder.

Answer (score 0):

This works well if your pages are php enabled, simply place this code at the very top of the old file and your visitors will be smoothly sent to the new location.

```
<?php
Header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
Header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
?>
```